# jquery: select by class inside a component

Tags: jquery

I have 3 jquery components in my page.

```
id=#table1

id=#table2

id=#table3
```

inside each table, there is a div whose class="black"

I need to select the div whole class is black inside table3

$(".black") : not good since it selects 3 divs

$("#table3.black"): not good since it selects table3 and not div whose class is black

Any idea ?

(something like .black#table3)

Answer (score 5):

You just need a space inside your ID -> class selector:

```
$("#table3 .black") 
// Selects elements with class .black that are children of an element 
//with ID #table3
```

You selector does this:

```
$("#table3.black") 
// Selects an element with ID table3 that also has a class .black
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you could use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$("#table3").find(".black")
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $("#table3 .black")
```